# coffeescript local compiler and coffeescript to js site output different results

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

If I compile this coffeescript to javascript using coffeescript compiler on my local machine:

```
window.App =
  Models: {}
  Views: {}
  Collections: {}
  Routers: {}
  init: ->
      Backbone.history.start()
```

I will end up with this generated javascript output:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.3
(function() {

  window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Views: {},
    Collections: {},
    Routers: {}
  };

  ({
    init: function() {
      var spotsList;
      spotsList = new App.Views.SpotsList();
      return Backbone.history.start();
    }
  });

}).call(this);
```

But, if I compile the same code in the online coffeescript to js http://js2coffee.org/ site I will get this result:

```
window.App = {
  Models: {},
  Views: {},
  Collections: {},
  Routers: {},
  init: function() {
    return Backbone.history.start();
  }
};
```

The latter seems more expected. I think this may be causing some problems in my project, but can't tell. I know that when I call App.init() my javascript console says it doesn't exist. Thanks for the help!

FIXED!

As @Rob W pointed out below, I had some tabs in my coffeescript code. Later I figured out it was because I had a clean install of TextMate and didn't have it set to "Soft Tabs (spaces)".

Comment: Coffeescript is not javascript. Learn javascript.

Comment: not sure what in my post made you think i thought coffeescript was javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two differences between your "local" and "online" result.

1. Local version is wrapped in a closure.
2. Local version's `init` method is dangling outside `App`.

The extra closure is the default behaviour of the `coffee` compiler. Use the `--bare` flag to not get rid of the wrapper:

```
coffee --bare --compile app.coffee
```

There's no reason for 2 to occur. Make sure that the spaces matches: If you've got four preceeding spaces before Models, etc, and three before init, then the output will be "wrong".

Comment: +1 thanks Rob W. something strange is going on and i'm trying to figure it out. i was thinking that the results from js to coffee site (the 2nd js result) were expected as opposed to the first result generated by my local coffee calls. i will try as you suggested

Comment: i tried --bare and it did get rid of the closure, but still, the major difference still exists, seems as though the init function is not available when calling App.init()

Comment: @botbot The input/output in your question does not match, which leads to the suggestion that you made a mistake when copying the source. The most likely cause for the dangling `input` method is a wrong indention (at least one space too less, to be precise).

Comment: seems like no mater how i change the app.coffee, tabs, spaces, i still end up with an init function that is outside of window.App namespace i intended it to be in...

Comment: @botbot I'm pretty sure that the compiler got it right. Share your coffee file (my mail is on my profile), and I'll have a quick look.

Comment: Summary from mail conversation: `app.coffee` contained mixed spaces and tabs, which lead to the error as explained in the answer. **Never mix tabs with spaces!**